# PHP - Delete via confirmation with bootstrap

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This is what i want to do i will give you a scenario. If i click the delete button the modal will pop up and ask if you want to delete or not. After clicking ok it will perform the query and delete it to database. Can someone give me ideas how to do it?

this is the picture of my grid.
[image]

here is my code.

```
 <?php
    include_once('connection.php');
  ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href ="css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    </head>
    <body>  
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="60">ID</th>
                    <th width="200">Title</th>
                    <th width="150">Date Posted</th>
                    <th>Content</th>
                    <th width="200">Image</th>
                    <th width="200">Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php

            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY news_id");
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['news_id']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['news_title']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['news_date']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['news_content']; ?></td>
                    <td><img style="height:150px; width:200px;" src="<?php echo $row['news_image']; ?>"  ></td>
                    <td>
                         <a href="edit2.php?newsid=<?php echo $row['news_id'];?>" class='btn btn-info left-margin'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</a>
                         <a class='btn btn-danger delete-object'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>


        <script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You will need to have Javascript for this

Comment: Have you tried with `onClick`, `confirm()`?

Comment: can i do it in bootstrap sir? i want some flashy design lol.

Comment: when clicked on DELETE button open a modal normally, in that u'll have OK / CANCEL buttons, when clicked on OK then do the necessary coding.. that would do ur task..

Comment: @Sougata i tried to onClick sir. But it's not working i don't know the reason why cant delete a data. And i want a bootstrap message.

Comment: @phpfresher can i do it without scripts?

Comment: yes u can do it without scripts and just using the bootstrap plugin and PHP code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Bootstrap dialogs](https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/) for showing dialogs. When showing a confirmation dialog, you can check if user clicked OK, then do an AJAX request to ex: list.php?delete_photo=31

```js
BootstrapDialog.confirm('Hi Apple, are you sure?', function(result){
            if(result) {
                alert('Yup.');
            }else {
                alert('Nope.');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

For a fancy way to do this, try modals:

```
 <?php
    include_once('connection.php');
  ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href ="css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    </head>
    <body>  
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="60">ID</th>
                    <th width="200">Title</th>
                    <th width="150">Date Posted</th>
                    <th>Content</th>
                    <th width="200">Image</th>
                    <th width="200">Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php

            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY news_id");
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['news_id']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['news_title']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['news_date']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['news_content']; ?></td>
                    <td><img style="height:150px; width:200px;" src="<?php echo $row['news_image']; ?>"  ></td>
                    <td>
                         <a href="edit2.php?newsid=<?php echo $row['news_id'];?>" class='btn btn-info left-margin'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</a>
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Delete</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Delete immage <?php echo $row['news_title']; ?> </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Are you sure you want to delte this immage?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" >Delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>


        <script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Modal example is from w3schools, you can read more there.
Modal is the fanciest way to do this, search and read more...

Best regards,

M.I.